# if else condition failing with error

Tags: java, if-statement

I have an if-else condition inside a ksh script.

My code:

```
ORACLESID=`echo $ORACLE_SID`
if [$ORACLESID="KFBACRMW"] ; then
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/${ORACLE_SID}/dbhome
fi

export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Its setting default home its not picking mention home in condition
`"ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/${ORACLE_SID}/dbhome"`

Error:

```
ORACLESID=KFBACRMW
+ [KFBACRMW=KFBACRMW]
dba_pre_snap_test.ksh[34]: [KFBACRMW=KFBACRMW]:  not found
```

Comment: Please add some format and indentation to the code, and also tell us what language are you using and what are you trying to achieve with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this would work:

```ksh
ORACLESID=`echo $ORACLE_SID`
if [["x$ORACLESID"="xKFBACRMW"]]; then
    export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/${ORACLE_SID}/dbhome
fi

export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

btw, this is not `.java`, is `.ksh`, it has the wrong label. Regarding indentation, I understand why some old `.ksh` are not.

Comment: Its not JAVA its ksh. I will try to above portion will let you know that for answer,  Thanks for your help.

Comment: It didn't work, filed with same error. 
+ [[xKFBACRMW=xKFBACRMW]]
dba_pre_snap_test.ksh[34]: [[xKFBACRMW=xKFBACRMW]]:  not found

Comment: did you see the `"` (double-quote) char? `[["x$ORACLESID"="xKFBACRMW"]];`. I presume your `$ORACLESID` is empty, thus comparing `null` against `string`.